# simplejson parsing json error

Tags: django, json

I'm sending the following json message via POST request:

```
{
    “ID”:”17”,
    “FIRST_NAME”:”John”,
    “LAST_NAME”:”Doe”,
    “TOKEN”:”8cdde0ef552e305cb44e143d3f8c742fb35caab8f360e7”
}
```

I'm loading the json in django by `json_message=simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)` and I keep getting the following exception:

`Expecting property name: line 2 column 1 (char 2)`

Does anybody know what the issue is? I searched this online and not finding it. I was able to parse the exact same json message in another app using the Play! framework, so i'm not sure if there is something specific to django I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the quotes.

```
{
    "ID" : "17",
    "FIRST_NAME" : "John",
    "LAST_NAME" : "Doe",
    "TOKEN" : "8cdde0ef552e305cb44e143d3f8c742fb35caab8f360e7"
}
```

I tried it and it worked.